# OPENLAYERS 6 how to get the bounds of several kml file

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

How can i get the bounds of several kml file ?
i can get easely for one kml file but i am a little be lost ... to get the bounds of all kml file who are in the map ...

here is the code (write in php file context)

at first i define the kml file needed  and the js var for sources and layers (ie : src_expe_pro0   expe_pro0 ...)

```
$pro_kml .= '
   var src_expe_pro'.$j.' =new ol.source.Vector({
      url: "http://www.grottes-et-karsts-de-chine.org/gkc_kml_file/pro_kml_file/'.strtolower($pro_id).'.kml",
      format: new ol.format.KML()
   });
   var expe_pro'.$j.' = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source:src_expe_pro'.$j.'
    });';   
   $layers_pro_kml .= "expe_pro".$j.",
   ";
```

later i put this in the map (so $layers_pro_kml can be one or several layer(s))

```
...
         layers: [
            fond_carte,
            '.$layers_pro_kml.'
            expe_markers
         ],
...
```

and here come the fog ...
for now i simply use this who work taking the bound of the first kml layer

```
   expe_pro0.once("change", function(e){
      var extension = src_expe_pro0.getExtent();
      map.getView().fit(extension);
   });
```

so in fact the question is how to work with the arrays (extension) to reduce at one array we will give me the bounds of all the kml layers ?
is there a fonction in the api or must i play with the arrays ?? or perhaps a simple way ?

Any advice

Thanks

With the advice of mike (thanks) i use this and its work perfectly ..

```
      var extension = ol.extent.createEmpty();
      map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer){
         if(!layer.values_.id) {
            layer.once("change", function(e){
               ol.extent.extend(extension, layer.getSource().getExtent());
               map.getView().fit(extension);
            });
         }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.  The sources might load in any order so it would be simplest to re-fit as each loads.

```
     // before opening map set listeners for vectors loading
     // and use extents to fit the map
     var extension = ol.extent.createEmpty();
     [
        fond_carte,
        '.$layers_pro_kml.'
        expe_markers
     ].forEach(function(layer) {
       if (layer.getSource().getExtent) {
         layer.getSource().on("addfeature", function(e){
           ol.extent.extend(extension, layer.getSource().getExtent());
           map.getView().fit(extension);
         });
       }
     });
     // then open the map to load the vectors
     map.setView(
       new ol.View({
         center: [0,0],
         zoom: 0
       })
     );
```

Comment: thanks but i get 
TypeError: layer.getSource().getExtent is not a function. (In 'layer.getSource().getExtent()', 'layer.getSource().getExtent' is undefined)

Comment: Are you only including vector layers?

Comment: You are only interested in vectors so you could limit the list or add a test to see if the source supports getExtent()

Comment: yes i triying a condition with the id of the values_ of the OSM layer

Comment: `if (layer.getSource().getExtent) {` will restrict it to sources which support `getExtent()`

Comment: yes i see try and i have nothing on the map  but no error for now

Comment: now i got this AssertionError: Assertion failed. See https://openlayers.org/en/v6.0.0/doc/errors/#25 for details.
K — Feature.js:1
fit — View.js:1018
gkc_ol_load — gkc_rcexd.php:398
Page actualisée à 20:45:13
K — Feature.js:1

Comment: A "change" event may fire before any features have been added. 
 Try using `layer.getSource().on("addfeature", function(e){` instead.

Comment: white map ... without error .... i think i will try to write something similar outside of new ol.Map  ???

Comment: You must open the map with a center and zoom ([0,0] and 0 will suffice) to get the vectors to load.  Then you read their extends to fir the map.